# CPU vs GPU number of cores

Tags: gpu, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-cores

I need some help understanding the concept of cores on a GPU vs. cores in a CPU for the purpose of doing parallel calculations.

When it comes to cores in a CPU, it seems pretty simple. I have a super intensive "for" loop that iterates four times. I have four cores in my Intel i5 2.26GHz CPU. I give one loop to each core. Each of the four loops is independent of the other. Boom - I now have four threads created and 100% CPU usage (instead of 25% CPU usage with only one core). My "for" loop now runs almost four times faster than it would have if I did not parallelize it.

In contrast, I don't even know the number of cores in my laptop's GPU (Intel Graphics Media Accelerator HD, or Intel HD Graphics, with 1696MB shared memory) that I can use for parallel calculations. I don't even know a valid way of comparing the GPU to the CPU. When I see compute unit = 6 on my graphics card description, I wonder if that means the graphics card has 6 cores for parallelization that can work kinda like the 4 cores in a CPU, except that the GPU cores run at 500MHz [slow] instead of 2.26GHz [fast]?

So, would you please fill some of the gaps or mistakes in my knowledge or help me compare the two? I don't need a super complicated answer, something as simple as "You can't compare a CPU core with a GPU core because of blankity blank" or "a GPU core isn't really a core like a CPU core is" would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A GPU core isn't really a core like a CPU core is.

Answer (score 0):

GPU core is technically different from a CPU core in its design. GPU cores are optimized for vectorized code's execution unlike the CPU cores. Hence, the speedup you would get with GPU comparedto CPU is not only dependent on the number of cores but it also depends on the extent to which the code could be vectorized. You can check the specifications of your computer's GPU to find the number of cores. You can use CUDA/ OpenCL depending on the GPU on your machine.

Comment: Execution speed on a CPU also depends on how well your code vectorizes.  If you avoid bottlenecking on DRAM bandwidth, summing small to medium arrays of `float` that fit in L1d or L2 cache can be about 16x to 64x faster on a single CPU core if vectorized well vs. serial `sum += arr[i]` without `-ffast-math` or anything.  (8 vectors per AVX vector, for a CPU like Skylake where FP addition has 2/clock throughput but 4 cycle latency, so another factor of 8.)  [What makes numpy.sum faster than an optimized (auto-vectorized) C loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77823375)