# Why does numba speed up a process by ~175 times on a 10 core processor?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu, numba

I have gotten roughly similar results on two machines: one with an Intel i5-1235U (10 cores, 2 performance cores, 12 total threads) and the other with an Intel i7-13700KF (16 cores, 8 performance cores, 24 total threads).

I am trying to get into parallel computing and have written a simple script to compare times of serial vs parallel tasks with numba. The process in question is the generation of n random integers between 0 and 9. I would expect that the maximum amount by which a process could be sped up would be 12x or 24x on this hardware, i.e., the total threads. However, I am seeing performance increase of up to 175x. If the number of thread is not the limiting factor, then was is? Does the extra performance come from hyper-threading?

I have attached plots that compare the results.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, prange
import time

@jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def generate_random_vector_parallel(n):
    vector = np.empty(n, dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in prange(n):
        vector[i] = np.random.randint(0, 10)
    return vector


def generate_random_vector_serial(n):
    vector = np.empty(n, dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(n):
        vector[i] = np.random.randint(0, 10)
    return vector

n = 10000
n_linspace = range(1, n + 1)
parallel_times = np.zeros(n)
serial_times = np.zeros(n)


def iterate(i):
    parallel_start_time = time.time()
    parallel_random_vector = generate_random_vector_parallel(i)
    parallel_time_difference = time.time() - parallel_start_time
    parallel_times[i - 1] += parallel_time_difference

    serial_start_time = time.time()
    serial_random_vector = generate_random_vector_serial(i)
    serial_time_difference = time.time() - serial_start_time
    serial_times[i - 1] += serial_time_difference

superiterations = 10

for m in range(superiterations):
    for n in n_linspace:
        iterate(n)

parallel_times = parallel_times / superiterations
serial_times = serial_times / superiterations

serial_over_parallel = [
    serial / parallel for serial, parallel in zip(serial_times, parallel_times)
]



# Block to plot with matplotlib
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf

pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("output.pdf")

fig1 = plt.figure()
plt.title("Average execution time of random vector of length\n(parallel) (n=100)")
plt.ylabel("Average execution time (s)")
plt.xlabel("Length of vector")
plt.plot(n_linspace[1:], parallel_times[1:], color="blue")
plt.show()

fig2 = plt.figure()
plt.title("Average execution time of random vector of length\n(serial) (n=100)")
plt.ylabel("Average execution time (s)")
plt.xlabel("Length of vector")
plt.plot(n_linspace[1:], serial_times[1:], color="red")
plt.show()

fig3 = plt.figure()
plt.title("Average execution time of random vector of length\n(parallel) (n=100)")
plt.ylabel("log Average execution time (s)")
plt.xlabel("log Length of vector")
plt.loglog(n_linspace[1:], parallel_times[1:], color="blue")
plt.loglog(n_linspace[1:], serial_times[1:], color="red")
plt.show()

fig4 = plt.figure()
plt.title("Average execution time of random vector of length\n(parallel) (n=100)")
plt.ylabel("(avg serial execution time) /(avg parallel execution time)")
plt.xlabel("Length of vector")
plt.plot(n_linspace[1:], serial_over_parallel[1:], color="grey")
plt.show()

pdf.savefig(fig1)
pdf.savefig(fig2)
pdf.savefig(fig3)
pdf.savefig(fig4)

pdf.close()
```

Plots:

[image: Parallel speed]

[image: Serial speed]

[image: loglog of both speeds]

[image: serial speed / parallel speed]

Comment: Here you're comparing a parallel compiled version of the function with a non-parallel non-compiled version. The former is faster not just because it takes advantage of multiple cores, but because compilation enables it to avoid slow `for` looping in Python. If you want a clean comparison of serial vs parallel, you could `@jit` compile both functions, but have one with `parallel=True` and the other with `parallel=False`.

Comment: Indeed. The bottleneck initially is the _python interpreter_ having to work on the `for` loop. Python is classically considered a slow language because it's interpreted so the fact you used `jit` doesn't mean you _just_ overcame the GIL to parellelize your loop, you removed tonnes of runtime overhead, which is the dominating factor

Comment: This makes sense. Completely forgot to account for python being interpreted. Further tests using `@jit` with `parallel=False` as suggested by @slothrop provides parallel times that are <12 times shorter than serial (running on i7 machine now). Should I expect 16 or 24 to be an expected maximum (physical cores vs # of threads)?

Comment: Depends on the workload whether it can occupy a physical core's throughput resources or not.  If not, and the bottleneck is mostly latency, such as summing an array in a naive way (`sum += arr[i]` with strict FP semantics that prevent unrolling, let alone vectorization), then two logical threads can share the same physical core and each start an `addsd` instruction every 4 clocks, for a 2x speedup.  (Still leaving vast amounts of performance on the table: [What makes numpy.sum faster than an optimized (auto-vectorized) C loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77822968) )

Comment: By contrast, well-optimized code that already runs 2 FP add instructions (scalar or SIMD) per clock cycle with just a single thread isn't going to benefit from more.  And if cache footprint is a factor like in a well-tuned matmul, might slow down if competing for that limited cache space with another thread on the same core.